# How to represent a curly brace in regex replace using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, escaping, curly-braces

I want to be able to do the following string replacement:

```
Input: 3^4
Output: 3^{4}
```

I have written the following regex expression to solve it:

```
outputString=outputString.replace(/\^(-?[1-9][0-9]*)/g,"\^"+"{"+"$1"+unescape('}'));
```

The output escapes the braces to be something like: `3^/{4/}`

Can someone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: Solution to what? What's the question? Seems to work exactly like you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/Rm8aq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
'3^4'.replace(/\^(\d+)/, '^{$1}');  // -> 3^{4}
```

Comment: you are right. there is no problem with the regex. The second regex works too in an independent browser. It is probably the software environment I am working in..which is somehow escaping the characters..Thanks for the help.